# Deploy python file on Google BigTable. How to use package google-cloud-bigtable in python

Tags: python, bigtable

I try to deploy python file with MapReduce on google cloud BigTable. But I don't know how to do it. How to start? Is google-cloud-bigtable available? Are there any courses about it? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you are attempting to solve thus, we would appreciate it if you could rewrite your question clarifying your use case. Could you briefly explain what you are trying to solve and what you have tried in more detail. Regarding google-cloud-bigtable library, it is indeed available. https://googleapis.dev/python/bigtable/latest/index.html should be a good starting point to learn about it. Thanks!.

Comment: Tkanks for help. I have already read this documentation.